# How do I remove Ensure text remains visible during webfont load in Google pagespeed insights?

Tags: wordpress, pagespeed-insights

I am currently solving this issue and I am out of options,
I tried using Pre party plugin to preload the font but i am still having this error.

[image]

this font is stored locally from my theme.

anyone can help me with this?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

in font-face, add this propertry:

```
 font-display:swap;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll tell you what I did (and continue to do, heh:).
It usually happens to me ONLY 2 (two) times: 1) When I update Elementor - 2) When I update another plugin called Mobile Menu.
That said, what I do is +/- simple;
a) I see the Pagespeed report - b) I copy and paste the link to which it is attributed (for example; http://yourdomain/wp-content/plugins/whatever plugin it is/the file it is in/the name of the.css file) in a note block (to know which file to edit).
c) I go to my file manager/search for the file/edit it adding what was indicated in a previous answer (That is, fonto-display:swap).
I save everything/Clear ALL caches and... so!

And I say I still do it because, unfortunately, NONE of the developers (neither Elementor nor the other plugin) do ANYTHING to change this.

Ergo, I have to do it with every new update of both plugins.

Answer (score -1):

Oh. And one more thing (that I forgot to tell you)...
What Pagespeed tells you is the name of the source(s) that is giving you THAT "problem".
But these fonts are loaded from a .css file.
Ergo, you will have to search for the path of said file.
For example, in my case that I use Elementor, the path in question is: public_html/wp-content/plugin/assets/lib/fontawesome (which is the ONLY font I have problems with)/css/fontawesome.min.css
And this is INDEPENDENT of whether you have custom fonts (like me, heh:) well, this font is, as you say is your case, a SPECIFIC PART of the Elementor "package".
That is to say, in my case ALL my texts have a single (custom) font.
However, fontawesone is the one that Elementor uses, for example, for menus (when opening them), etc.
So I can't do ANYTHING to avoid it.
And the same thing happens to me with the other plugin (which obviously has a different file path) but exclusively for the symbol it uses, precisely to show the menu on cell phones, heh.
Ergo. You will have to look for the CSS file that this font is generating, enter and edit it (adding font-display:swap).
Hope this can help you.
See you.

Comment: please delete this and edit it into your previous answer post.